# Heeding exceptions thrown when setting Spring Boot configuration properties

Tags: java, validation, configuration, spring-boot

I noticed that my Spring Boot (1.3.2) application continues to execute when an essential configuration property cannot be parsed. Here is an example component to illustrate.

```
@Service
@EnableConfigurationProperties(Runner.RunnerConfiguration.class)
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "runner")
  public static class RunnerConfiguration {

    private ZonedDateTime theTime;

    public void setTheTime(String theTime) {
      try {
        this.theTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(theTime);
      } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to parse string", e);
      }
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getTheTime() {
      return theTime;
    }
  }

  @Autowired
  RunnerConfiguration config;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) {
    System.out.println("The time = " + config.getTheTime());
  }
}
```

When I run a `SpringBootApplication` with this component and pass `--runner.theTime=now` on the command line, I expected that the application would fail with an `IllegalArgumentException` since "now" cannot be parsed. However, instead the application keeps running and the output is:

```
The time = null
```

The way that I can get the failure to happen is to inject a validator bean as part of the application. The validator doesn't have to validate anything.

```
@Bean
public Validator configurationPropertiesValidator() {
  return new Validator() {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
      return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    }
  };
}
```

I peeked into Spring Boot code, and it looks like even though the `IllegalArgumentException` is caught and added to a list of exceptions kept in the binding result, `PropertiesConfigurationFactory` will not look at the list unless there is a validator. See: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.2.RELEASE/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/bind/PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java#L270